# I am getting the columns name but not the data for the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have given these commands as shown in the picture but i am not able to see the data

[image]

I am trying to see the whole data not just the column but i am only getting column names i have already tries sorting but it did not work.
I have watched the videos on you tube nothing is working

Comment: Do not post code as pictures

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question so as to share [code and data as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).  To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your dataframe columns do not have any values.
To answer this earlier code will need to be shown.
Have you checked the data has been imported correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to see your whole dataframe? I'm not sure what you're trying to see here.
Use `print(df)` and you can see the whole data.

If you're only trying to see Age, Orders, and Amount, try dropping the columns User_ID, Marital_Status, Status, and unnamed1. To drop columns, you can do this: `df.drop(columns=['col1', 'col2'])`

Answer (score 0):

try to know data types by running:
`df.dtypes`
or
`df.info()`
then you may know the data type in your data frame.
Moreover, to check whether your data frame has null values:
`df.isnull()`